# Asignar nombres de columnas a la clase JTable

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo una simple aplicación donde un array de datos paso a un *JTable*, especifico los nombres de las columnas de la table, pero solo se visualizan los datos pero no los nombres de las columnas.

Aquí el código:

```
public class TableTest extends JFrame
{
    private String() columnNames = ("Planet", "Radius", "Moons", "Geseous", "Color");
    private Object[][] cells = 
    {
        {"Mercury", 2440.0, 0, false, Color.YELLOW},
        {"Venus", 6052 .0, 0, false, Color.YELLOW},
        {"Earth", 71492.0, 16, true, Color.BLUE},
        {"Mars", 3397.0, 2, false, Color.RED},
        {"Jupiter", 71492.0, 16, true, Color.ORANGE},
        {"Saturn", 60268.0, 18, true, Color.ORANGE},
        {"Uranus", 25559.0, 17, true, Color.BLUE},
        {"Neptune", 24766.0, 8, true, Color.BLUE},
        {"Pluto", 1137.0, 1, false, Color.BLACK}
    };

    public TableTest()
    {
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (cells, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable (model);
        table. setAutoCreateRowSorter (true);
        add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print");
        printButton.addActionListener.(
          EventHandler.create(ActionListener.class, table, "print")
        );
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(printButton);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
    };
};
```

Cómo se visualiza la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podría solucionar agregando el `JTable` a Un `JScrollPane` ->  `add(new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);`

Comment: Creo que tienes los nombres arriba pero no los ves porque es muy pequeña tu ventana.

Comment: Plutón ya no es un planeta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega el `JTable` a un [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) antes de añadirlo al `JFrame`.

```
add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Si no utilizas un `JScrollPane`, de acuerdo con la documentación de [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html):

> Tenga en cuenta que si desea utilizar una `JTable` en una vista independiente (fuera de `JScrollPane`) y desea que el encabezado aparezca, lo puede conseguir usando `getTableHeader()` y lo mostrará por separado.

```
TableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(cells,columnNames);
JTable table = new JTable(modelo);
/* Accedemos al header de forma individual */
JTableHeader header = tabla.getTableHeader();
add(table ,BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(header  ,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```